# PHP OAUTH2 "error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The specified authorization code cannot be used by this client application."

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am working on setting up authorization in a php application with oauth2 and am struggling to get a access token back.  I get the error {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The specified authorization code cannot be used by this client application."}
I cannot find evidence of this error anywhere.  I imagine this error may come from mismatched return urls but since mine come from the same variable I'm not sure how that could be.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['code'])){

    $access_token = getAccessToken($_POST["code"]);
    
    $resource = getResource($access_token);
    


}else if(!isset($_POST['code'])){
    header( "Location: https://growthzoneapp.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$CLIENT_ID &response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=$REDIRECT_URI&scope=openid+profile"
);
}


function getAccessToken($authorization_code) {
 global $CLIENT_ID, $CLIENT_SECRET, $REDIRECT_URI;


 $content = "grant_type=authorization_code&code=$authorization_code&client_id=$CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET&redirect_uri=$REDIRECT_URI";



$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://growthzoneapp.com/oauth/token',
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>  $content  ,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}



}
```

Comment: `invalid_grant` basically means that the `authorization_code` you are passing to the `oauth/token` endpoint is invalid or has expired. See the OAuth RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) for a detailed description. From your code, it is not clear where the authorization code you are sending comes from, so you will need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the client ID in the authorization request doesn't match the client ID in the access token request.  In this case there is an extra space added in the authorization request "$CLIENT_ID &":

```
 header( "Location: https://growthzoneapp.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=$CLIENT_ID &response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=$REDIRECT_URI&scope=openid+profile"
```